# ios app exit gracefully after handling a crash

Tags: ios

I have written my own crash handler for my iOS app - the reason why I did not use an existing one like Flurry or Crashlytics is not important.

My problem is that I am not able to call the default signal handler or exit the app gracefully. Instead after the app crashes it freezes on the last screen it was when it crashed instead of exiting the app like it would if I was not hooking on to signals.

My crash handler is simple and works fine. But the default handler is not called or the app does not close.

> ```
> struct sigaction newSigAction;
> static struct sigaction oldSigAction;
> newSigAction.sa_sigaction = iOSSignalHandler;
> newSigAction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
> sigemptyset(&newSigAction.sa_mask);
> sigaction(SIGQUIT, &newSigAction, &oldSigAction);
> ... (more signals attached to)
>
> void iOSSignalHandler(int signal, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
>   // handle crash
>   // then call default handler
>   (*oldSigAction.sa_sigaction)(signal, info, context);
> }
> ```

I tried calling exit(0) but is there a better way to exit the app gracefully?

*EDIT*

To be more precise how do the crash reporting tools such has FLurry and Crashlytics handle the signal and exit the app, because in my case the default signal handler does not fire despite me calling it

Comment: The apple view is that only iOS or the user can terminate the app, so there's really no such thing as a graceful exit.

Comment: let me rephrase - how do the crash reporting tools such has FLurry and Crashlytics handle the signal and exit the app